# Potentially corrupt file system, unable to boot back into linux partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, grub2, dualboot

I've had this issue for a while and not found any solutions on all the other grub related posts.
I think this may have been caused by some windows 10 update that killed my grub config.
When I boot I get the GRUB> command line with (hd0,0)--(hd0,6) showing. (I get more if my bootable linux usb is plugged in)

running ls (hd0,0)/ I get unknown filesystem for all partitions except (hd0,2)/
The result of this command shows the files:

- EFI
- - Boot
- - - bootx64.efi
- - - fbx64.efi
- - - mmx64.efi
- - Microsoft
- - - Boot
- - - - Some DLLs
- - - Recovery
- - - - BCD and Logs
- - ubuntu
- - - BOOTX64.CSV  grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi  shimx64.efi
- 'system volume information'

Normally when I see grub repairs people either get back into their system by booting from the grub command line or by mounting, chrooting and then doing the repair.
The issues is, none of the files people talk about when booting from grub (vmlinuz) are present in that partition. Furthermore, I can boot to a USB ubuntu for trial but I am unable to mount the partitions for chrooting.

The command lsblk -l outputs:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# lsblk -l
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0   7:0    0     2G  1 loop /rofs
loop1   7:1    0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop2   7:2    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop3   7:3    0 255.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop4   7:4    0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop5   7:5    0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/467
sda     8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
sda1    8:1    0   499M  0 part 
sda2    8:2    0    99M  0 part /mnt
sda3    8:3    0    16M  0 part 
sda4    8:4    0 249.9G  0 part 
sda5    8:5    0   576M  0 part 
sda6    8:6    0 214.7G  0 part 
sdb     8:16   1  28.7G  0 disk 
sdb1    8:17   1  28.7G  0 part /cdrom
```

dev/sda2 is the only partition I can mount.

When I run fdisk -l:

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1023999   1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2    1024000   1226751    202752    99M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1226752   1259519     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1259520 525271443 524011924 249.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  525273088 526452735   1179648   576M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  526454784 976771071 450316288 214.7G Linux filesystem
```

Among descriptions of some of the loop systems.

Another thing to note which may help is that I can boot my windows system. Just when I change boot order to the linux partition it goes straight to the grub command line. And the other way around and no grub shows, it just goes straight to windows.
Honestly any help on this matter would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I'm running fdisk -l from a bootable usb with a trial of Ubuntu. `file -s /dev/sda6` returns:

`/dev/sda6: data`

Comment: At this point I'm now just looking to be able to mount /dev/sda6 so that I can recover some files as nowhere seems to have the answer

Comment: I'm starting to think that its a corrupted partition, `parted -l` and `lsblk -f` both don't display a file system type for the partition and mount wont work because `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda6, missing codepage or helper program, or other error`

Comment: What type of filesystem _should_ it be? `ext4`? Try this - it won't change anything `e2fsck -n /dev/sda6`. See if it can find a backup superblock and that it starts to make sense of the remainder of the filesystem

Comment: This returns `The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device> 
or 
e2fsck -b 32768 <device>`

Another thing which lends the idea that it is corrupt is that Gparted says `warning unable to detect filesystem. Possible reasons are:
- file system is damaged
- file system is unknown to gparted`

Comment: cont ^^ `-there is no file system available - the device entry /dev/sda6 is missing`

Comment: I should also add that running the suggested commands with alternative superblocks yields the exact same error message